# How to type '$' in jupyter notebook text cell?

Tags: jupyter-notebook

When I try to type $ in the text cell of Jupyter notebook then it is recognized as a special character for math typesetting. How to prevent this? I have tried using '\$' but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this some time ago and ended up double escaping it:

```
\\$test\\$
```

This will result in `$test$`

I'm not sure if this is the official way to do it though.